# How to inject arguments to a constructor of a service for testing using jasmine testbed.configureTestingModule

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi I need to pass two arguments to my constructor when testing using testBed.configureModule

Here is my base.service.spec.ts

```ts
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { BaseService } from '@shared/services/base/base.service';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('BaseService', () => {

    let baseService: BaseService<any>, httpClientTestingModule: HttpClientTestingModule;

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [BaseService,
                { provide: HttpClientTestingModule, useValue: httpClientTestingModule },
                { provide: String, useValue: 'base' }
            ]
        })

        baseService = TestBed.get(BaseService)
        //httpClientTestingModule = TestBed.get(HttpClientTestingModule)

    })

    const GET_BASE_URL = 'getBaseURL'
    //Test getBaseUrl
    it(`${GET_BASE_URL} should return a string`, () => {

        baseService.getBaseURL().then((base) => {
            if (base) {
                //PASSED if base is a string
                expect(base).toEqual(jasmine.any(String), 'Result is not a string')
            } else {
                fail(`${GET_BASE_URL} failed: string was empty or null`)
            }
        }, (error) => {
            fail(`${GET_BASE_URL} failed: promise was not resolved`)
        })

    })

    const GET_PROVIDER_HEADER = 'getProviderOnlyHeader'
    //Test getProviderOnlyHeader
    it(`${GET_PROVIDER_HEADER} should return HttpHeaders`, () => {

        let result = baseService.getProviderOnlyHeader()

        expect(result).toEqual(jasmine.any(HttpHeaders), 'Result is not a HttpHeader')
    })

})
```

And here is a portion of my base.service.ts

```ts
export class BaseService<T> {

  nativeStorage: NativeStorage;

  //A single object
  _item = new BehaviorSubject<T>(null);

  //A list of items
  _list = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>(null);

  get item() {
    return this._item.asObservable();
  }

  getCurrentItem() {
    return this._item.getValue()
  }

  getCurrentList() {
    return this._list.getValue()
  }

  get list() {
    return this._list.asObservable();
  }

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public controllerName: string) {

    this.nativeStorage = new NativeStorage();

    this.getBaseURL().then((base) => {
      BASE = base
    })
  }
}
```

I know there are similar questions but I can't find a solution
How should my testBed setup look like?

Anymore detail required let me know thanks in advance

Also getting this error message

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for BaseService: (?, ?).

Also base service is a super class, its not really a service
The base service arguments are injected in the super method, example below

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccessService extends BaseService<any> {

    private _providers = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    get providers() {
        return this._providers.asObservable();
    }

    currentProviders() {
        return this._providers.getValue();
    }

    constructor(http: HttpClient) {
        super(
            http,
            controllerName)

        this.getBaseURL().then((base) => {
            BASE = base
        })
    }

    getProviders() {
        return this.http.get<any>(BASE + docketName + environment.API_V2 + 'providers')
            .pipe(
                map(resp => {
                    return resp.content
                }),
                tap(result => {
                    this._providers.next(result)
                })
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: And how are you passing `controllerName` in `service.ts` ?? The service is initialized by angular and you dont have control to pass `controllerName:string` ? How have u resolved your dependency in working code ? I'll provide my answer for test case once I get an answer for this query

Comment: @ShashankVivek refer to new code added

Comment: that's interesting scenario, I think that u wont be able to test `BaseService` using `angular` way because it operates outside of angular scope (since u are not using it as `providedIn: 'root'` ) . You can write a normal `Jasmine` test case for it as a `typescript` class. And then, write proper `angular` tests for `AccessService`